# when does innodb deliver updates to row data in buffer and disk?

Tags: innodb

I have a question about when does innodb update row data in the buffer and when does the change go to the disk. This question comes from the reading to undo log which says the history data are in the undo log waiting for rollbacks. If the engine needs undo log for rollback, changes of an update query must have changed the row before commit? And then what does the commit do since the data have already been updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE` a row:

Quick summary:

1. Fetch the block containing the row (or the block that should contain the row).  2. Insert/update/delete the row.
2. Mark the block as "dirty".  It will eventually be written to disk.
3. Put non-unique secondary index changes in the "change buffer"

More details (on those steps):

1. To find the 16KB block, drill down the `PRIMARY KEY's` BTree.  If the block is not in the buffer_pool (which is allocated in RAM), fetch it from disk.  (This may involve bumping some other block out of the buffer_pool.
2. Copy the previous value (in case of Update/Delete) to the undo log, and prep it for flushing to disk.
3. A background task flushes dirty pages to disk.  If all is going smoothly, 'most' of the buffer_pool contains non-dirty pages, and you 'never' have to wait for a 'free' block in the buffer_pool.
4. The Change Buffer is sort of a "delayed write" for index updates.  It is transparent.  That is, subsequent index lookups will automagically look in the change buffer and/or the index's BTree.  The data in the CB will eventually be blended with the real index BTree and eventually flushed to disk.

`UNIQUE` keys:  All `INSERTs` and `UPDATEs` that change the Unique key's column(s) necessarily check for dup-key rather than going through the change buffer.

`AUTO_INCREMENT` has some other special actions.

Depending on the values of `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit` and `innodb_doublewrite` something may be flushed to disk at the end of the transaction.  These handle "atomic" transactions and "torn pages".

Replication: Other activity may include writing to and syncing the binlog, and pushing data to other nodes in the cluster.

The design is "optimistic" in that it is optimized for `COMMIT` at the expense of `ROLLBACK`.  After a Commit, a process runs around purging the copies that were kept in case of a crash and Rollback.  A Rollback is more complex in that it must put back the old copies of the rows.  (See also "history list".)

Search for some of the keywords I have mentioned; read some other web pages; then come back with a more specific question.

**Commit**

Let's look at it from a different side.  Each row, including non-yet-committed rows being changed/deleted, has a "transaction id".  All the rows for a given transaction have the same id.  So, even if there is a crash, InnoDB, knows what to cleanup.  `COMMIT` and `ROLLBACK` need to be 'atomic'; this is aided by having a single write to disk "says it all".  The only way for that to be possible is for the transaction id to be the key.  Keep in mind, there could be a million rows scattered around the buffer_pool and data files and logs waiting for the commit/rollback.

After the commit/rollback, InnoDB can leisurely run around cleaning up things.  For example, until a `UPDATE` is committed or rolled back, there are two copies of each row being changed.  One of the rows needs to be removed -- eventually.  Meanwhile, the two rows are on a "history list".  Any other transactions search through the history list to see which one row they are allowed to see -- `READ UNCOMMITTED` = latest row that has *not* been committed / rolled back; `READ COMMITTED` = latest row that *has* been committed / rolled back; etc.

If I understand it correctly, the undo log is an optimization.  For example, on a `DELETE` the "old values" of the rows are copied to the undo log, and the row is actually deleted from the data BTree.  The optimization here is that the undo log is serially written, while the BTree may involve a lot more blocks, scattered around the table.  Also, the normal processing of data blocks includes caching them in the buffer_pool.  For Commit, the records in the undo log are tossed.  For Rollback, there is the tedious effort of using the undo log for reconstruction.

Yes, the history list adds work for all other transactions touching your recently changed rows.  But it enables transaction-isolation-modes and aids in recovery from crashes.

Comment: I have more specific questions according to the process you've described. First, thanks for answering.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But I think the main confusing point for me is not the whole process, but which step happens before and which after this "commit". This is important because as far as I know: 1) data are changed to disk before commit, and that's why undo log are used to construct previous versions; 2) at the moment of commit what happened? I guess commit is marked in the row to make clear its committed, and should be read in read-committed isolation Level; and redo log are flushed so that data are not to be lost whether or not dirty have alread flushed to dish already. @Rick James

Comment: @makiXIE - I added a bunch more.

Comment: I think the answer still confuses me. I know there is a trx-id on each row to record the last trx to modify it, and I think the mark is before commit. (1) So how could a new-comming trx with a larger trxId know the row's trx-id is committed or still in changing? Because I don't think only transaction Id can explain this, but I don't find in innodb's doc anything about a commit-mark. @RickJames

Comment: (2) after commit, I think the undo log is not removed. because they still support for mvcc, so purging only happens after no outgoing versions still need the data. I concern more about when the user commits, in a synchronized way the  innodb must mark on the buffer of "commit mark" and redo log on disk (not undo log) so that change is truly persisted? @RickJames

Comment: @makiXIE - Somewhere (I don't know where) there is a list of still-active txn ids.  Since transactions are closed (committed or rolled back) in an unpredictable order, there can't be a simple "every txn id below xxx is closed".  (Is that what you mean by "commit-mark"?)

Comment: @makiXIE - (2) I don't know what signals "trx id yyy can be purged from the log now".  (And, yeah, I may have mixed up the redo- and undo-logs.)

Comment: thanks for the comments. I think the " alive transactions ids" make this mechanic work, and yes it is what I mean by "commit-mark"  (I guess at least exists some mechanics in InnoDB to show if the transaction in a row represents a commit or in-process transaction).